# Are "uses" and "usage" interchangeable when talking about different meanings of the same word?

Tags: word-usage

Another [ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4537/109190) gives a comprehensive explanation about "uses" and "usage".

Besides that, there might be some special cases. Consider the following example

> I'm not going to explain all the meanings of "get" today, I'm just going to focus on
>   two **uses** of "get". But if you want more explanation and other uses, please check your dictionary
>   because there are many ways to use the word "get".

where "uses" seem to mean *the way how we use the word "get"*. With this meaning, are "uses" and "usage" interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't interchangeable in that context, because you wouldn't say "two usages". The term "usage" is better reserved for multiple or all uses seen collectively.
"Today we'll discuss the usage of "get", in particular two uses that are of interest."

Comment: Thank you! Are "that are of interest" and "that are interesting" interchangeable here?

Comment: "Of interest" is formal, and states that the matter is important.    "Interesting" is less formal, and describes the attitude of the instructor about the matter. It  may not make any difference, because if the matter is important, the instructor should be interested. The two forms are almost synonymous, but there is a shade of difference.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! What does "the matter" refer to? Is it the date, the interest or something else?

Comment: I meant the "uses of 'get'" referred to in your post, or any other subject matter that an instructor might call interesting.