# Are "uses" and "usage" interchangeable when talking about different words?

Tags: word-usage

**Note**: This post is NOT a duplicate of [Are "uses" and "usage" interchangeable when talking about different meanings of the same word?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239878/109190), which is discussing the situation of the same word. Oppose to that, this post is discussing the situation of two words.

Per Cambridge Dictionary, the word "usage" could be used as plural. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/usage) also gives this example.

> Now these two usages are syntactically distinguished as c for the first, and c for the second.

Consider this example

> Spanish and Portuguese speakers often use
>   the preposition 'en'
>   where in English we use both 'on' and 'in'.
>   Two separate words with very different **uses** in English.

which uses "**uses**" to convey the meaning of "the ways we use those prepositions"

Does it mean the same if "**usage**" was substituted for "**uses**"?

> Two separate words with very different "**usage**" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Lexico, **[usage](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/usage)** is more like a "rule:" "Habitual or customary practice, especially as creating a right, obligation, or standard."

> Now these two usages are syntactically distinguished as c for the
>   first, and c for the second.

The "usages" above refer to syntactical "rules."

---

**[Use](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/use)** is more like a "possibility," so how something can be used: "the action of using something or the state of being used for some purpose."

> Spanish and Portuguese speakers often use the preposition 'en' where
>   in English we use both 'on' and 'in'. Two separate words with very
>   different uses in English.

In this example, the "uses" just tells that *en,* *in* and *on* are used differently, without explaining the actual grammar rules.

You can probably use either "usages" or "uses" in both examples, but the words have different emphases.

This may help a bit: [-age](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-age), as a suffix, can mean “aggregate,” for example, a track vs trackage (all tracks collectively) or use vs usage (all uses collectively as a rule).